# Autohotkey script to restart Service at certain time

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, autohotkey, windows-services, chrome-remote-desktop

The PC at my workplace has chrome remote desktop installed and allow me to work at home remotely. Occasionally the program fails and requires me to manually restart the service to get it works again (Task Manager -> Services -> right click on service -> restart).

Apparently a lot of Autohotkey guidance on the internet is for restarting an exe program instead of a service. 
I would like to know if there is a way to make it into a script and allow Autohotkey to automatically kill the service and restart it 8am everyday?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the service's recovery settings so it just restarts the service on a failure?  I can imagine a scenario where that might not work properly, but if Windows detects that the service has failed it can restart it automatically without needing a separate watchdog.

In Windows 7 you can open the services list as follows:

- Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services
- Or just run "services.msc" from the run dialog

Once the service list is active, find the line item of interest and open the properties for that service.

On the tabs at the top, select Recovery.

For recovery options, you can then set all 3 of the drop downs for 1st, 2nd and Subsequent failures to "Restart the Service"

Comment: Hi JJognston2, the current setting is already "Restart the Service" for all 3 failure. Which now leads me to think that the chrome remote desktop failure is not due to its background service, maybe the software itself is flawed. Still, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try also this (run the script as administrator):

```
; Replace "Service name" with the service name you want restart. 
; Make sure that you are using the correct service name 
; shown in the properties for that service (not the Display name).

#Persistent
SetTimer, restart_Service, 10000
return

        restart_Service:
    time = %A_Hour%%A_Min%
    If (time = 0800)
    {    
        SetTimer, restart_Service, off
        ; Stop the service
        RunWait, %comspec% /c "net stop Service name",, Hide 
        Sleep, 10000  ; Wait 10 seconds for the service to stopp (Just to be sure)
        ; Start the service 
        RunWait, %comspec% /c "net start Service name",, Hide 
        Sleep, 700000  ; sleep the rest of the 08:00 time.
        SetTimer, restart_Service, on
    }
    return
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This actually works if I run the autohotkey exe as administrator.